# How to merge data frame keeping size same as the big dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe

I have these two dataframes:

```
df1 = data.frame(CustomerId = c(1:6), Product = c(rep("Toaster", 3), rep("Radio", 3)))
df2 = data.frame(CustomerId = c(2L, 4L, 7L), State = c(rep("Alabama", 2), rep("Ohio", 1)))
```

I am interested in merging only those rows that are present in df1.

I tried
`merge(x = df1, y = df2, by = "CustomerId", all = TRUE)`, but it is merging 7 rows. How do I avoid merging the last row, keeping only all 6 rows of df1.

`7          7    <NA>    Ohio`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We need `all.x` instead of `all`.  The 'x' and 'y' are input arguments for `merge` which represents the 'df1' and 'df2' respectively.  If we use `all`, then it implies a full join that includes the rows from both the 'df1' and 'df2'.  By specifying, `all.x`, it does a left join and if it is `all.y`, it does right join.  Without specifying anything, it does inner join

```
merge(x = df1, y = df2, by = "CustomerId", all.x = TRUE)
```